Modelica - Derivatives of input variables problem with dymola
I want to write a modelica model for a temperature controlled pump with an additional heat-exchanger. The model should guarantee that a definied temperature difference between supply and return temperature is reached. For the resulting massflux I implemented a pi(d)-controller.
But I cannot run the model neither with open modelica nor dymola. Thanks for your help!
Dymola gives the following error:

Translation of MultiSource.PumpTemperatureControlled
The DAE has 93 scalar unknowns and 93 scalar equations.
The model requires derivatives of some inputs as listed below:
1 inletTemperature
Translation aborted.
ERRORS have been issued.
model PumpTemperatureControlled
  // FMU REAL INPUTS

  // Parameter
  parameter Real maxFlowRate = 0.1;           // Maximaler Volumenstrom in m3/h
  parameter Real maxPressure = 10;            // Maximaler Druck in pa
  parameter Real minPressure = 10;            // Minimaler Druck in pa
  parameter Real desiredTempSpread = 4;       // Gewünschte Temperaturspreizung in K
  parameter Real densityRefrigerant = 1032;   // Dichte Kältemittel in kg/m3
  parameter Real zeta = 1;                    // Zeta-Wert Rohr
  parameter Real crossSectionAreaPipe = 0.01; // Rohrquerschnitt in m2 / PID-Regler Parameter
  parameter Real K_p = 1.0;                   // Proportionalitätsfaktor
  parameter Real T_i = 0.5;                   // Integralzeit
  parameter Real T_d = 0.2;                   // Ableitungszeit
  parameter Real x_min = -10.0;               // Untere Begrenzung des Integralanteils der Regelung
  parameter Real x_max = 10.0;                // Obere Begrenzung des Integralanteils der Regelung
  parameter Real capacityRefrigerant = 4180;

  // Variablen
  Real controlSignal(start=0, nominal=0);       // Steuersignal für die Pumpe
  Real currentTempSpread(start=0, nominal=4);   // Temperaturspreizung
  Real pressure(start=1000, nominal=60000);     // Druck Pumpe
  Real flowSpeed(start=0.3, nominal=0.3);       // Fließgeschwindigkeit
  Real controllerU(start=0, nominal=0), x(start=0, nominal=0), x_diff(start=0, nominal=0);

// Auslassmassestrom
  // INITIAL EQUATION
  Buildings.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T boundary(nPorts = 1, redeclare package Medium = Buildings.Media.Antifreeze.PropyleneGlycolWater(X_a = 0.40, property_T = 293.15) "Propylene glycol water, 40% mass fraction", use_m_flow_in = true, use_T_in = true)  annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {4, -36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Buildings.Fluid.MixingVolumes.MixingVolume vol(nPorts=2,   V = 0.01, redeclare package Medium = Buildings.Media.Antifreeze.PropyleneGlycolWater(X_a = 0.40, property_T = 293.15) "Propylene glycol water, 40% mass fraction", m_flow_nominal = 1, T_start = 293.15, p_start = 1e5)  annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin={34,14},    extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.PrescribedHeatFlow prescribedHeatFlow annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin={-14,36},    extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sensors.TemperatureSensor outletTemperatureHeatExchanger annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {54, 74}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput heatFlow annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-70, 36}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-110, 44}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}})));
input 
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput inletTemperature annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin={-72,-64},    extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-110, -58}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}})));
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput outletTempHeatExchanger annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {82, 42}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}), iconTransformation(origin = {108, 56}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary bou(redeclare package Medium = Buildings.Media.Antifreeze.PropyleneGlycolWater(X_a = 0.40, property_T = 293.15) "Propylene glycol water, 40% mass fraction", T = 303.15, nPorts = 1) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin={36,-66},    extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput massfluxHeatExchanger
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{66,-6},{86,14}})));
initial equation 
  x = 0.0;
  inletTemperature = 20.0;

// EQUATION
equation 
// Berechnung der Temperaturspreizung
  currentTempSpread = outletTemperatureHeatExchanger.T - inletTemperature;
// Proporitonalitätsanteil
  controllerU = desiredTempSpread - currentTempSpread;
// Differentialanteil
  x_diff = der(controllerU);
// Integralanteil
  der(x) = controllerU;
  when heatFlow < 1e-3 or x < x_min or x > x_max then
    reinit(controllerU, 0);
  end when;
// Berechnung des Steuersignals mit dem PID-Regler
  controlSignal = K_p*(controllerU + 1/T_i*x + T_d*x_diff);
// Begrenzung des Volumenstroms
  pressure = maxPressure - controlSignal;
// Berechnung der aktuellen Fließgeschwindigkeit
  flowSpeed = sqrt(2*pressure/(densityRefrigerant*zeta));
// Berechnung des aktuellen Massenstroms
  boundary.m_flow = flowSpeed*crossSectionAreaPipe*densityRefrigerant;

  massfluxHeatExchanger = boundary.m_flow;

  connect(boundary.ports[1], vol.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points={{14,-36},{36,-36},{36,4},{33,4}},          color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(prescribedHeatFlow.port, vol.heatPort) annotation(
    Line(points={{-4,36},{24,36},{24,14}},        color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(outletTemperatureHeatExchanger.port, vol.heatPort) annotation(
    Line(points={{44,74},{24,74},{24,14}},        color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(heatFlow, prescribedHeatFlow.Q_flow) annotation(
    Line(points={{-70,36},{-24,36}},                 color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(inletTemperature, boundary.T_in) annotation(
    Line(points={{-72,-64},{-8,-64},{-8,-32}},        color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(outletTempHeatExchanger, outletTemperatureHeatExchanger.T) annotation(
    Line(points={{82,42},{65,42},{65,74}},        color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(vol.ports[2], bou.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points={{35,4},{35,-36},{20,-36},{20,-66},{26,-66}},
                                                 color = {0, 127, 255}));
end PumpTemperatureControlled;

I tried to read some documentations. But I cannot find a solution so far.

The model is a bit strange to me. Some things I have noticed: (1) inletTemperature only has an initial value, no "real" equation for it. (2) heatFlow is an input and has no equation from what I see. I would strongly consider the answer by Rene Just Nielsen and rebuild the model graphically using sensors and blocks...

This is not a direct answer to your question but rather a recommendation: Since you are already using Modelica Buildings Library I suggest that you compose your model entirely "graphically" — i.e. using drag/drop of components (PI controller, heat exchanger, pump, differential temperature sensor etc.).
All components are available in MBL, they are well-tested and -documented.
Below is an example

This approach generally makes debugging of the model much easier, since each individual component is balanced (equal number of equations and unknowns)

One possibility is to send the inlet-temperature through a first order filter, or alternatively use some more advanced construct to have both the temperature and its derivative as input.
The first can be done as follows:
model PumpTemperatureControlled
  // FMU REAL INPUTS

  // Parameter
  parameter Real maxFlowRate = 0.1;           // Maximaler Volumenstrom in m3/h
  parameter Real maxPressure = 10;            // Maximaler Druck in pa
  parameter Real minPressure = 10;            // Minimaler Druck in pa
  parameter Real desiredTempSpread = 4;       // Gewünschte Temperaturspreizung in K
  parameter Real densityRefrigerant = 1032;   // Dichte Kältemittel in kg/m3
  parameter Real zeta = 1;                    // Zeta-Wert Rohr
  parameter Real crossSectionAreaPipe = 0.01; // Rohrquerschnitt in m2 / PID-Regler Parameter
  parameter Real K_p = 1.0;                   // Proportionalitätsfaktor
  parameter Real T_i = 0.5;                   // Integralzeit
  parameter Real T_d = 0.2;                   // Ableitungszeit
  parameter Real x_min = -10.0;               // Untere Begrenzung des Integralanteils der Regelung
  parameter Real x_max = 10.0;                // Obere Begrenzung des Integralanteils der Regelung
  parameter Real capacityRefrigerant = 4180;

  // Variablen
  Real controlSignal(start=0, nominal=0);       // Steuersignal für die Pumpe
  Real currentTempSpread(start=0, nominal=4);   // Temperaturspreizung
  Real pressure(start=1000, nominal=60000);     // Druck Pumpe
  Real flowSpeed(start=0.3, nominal=0.3);       // Fließgeschwindigkeit
  Real controllerU(start=0, nominal=0), x(start=0, nominal=0), x_diff(start=0, nominal=0);

// Auslassmassestrom
  // INITIAL EQUATION
  Buildings.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T boundary(nPorts = 1, redeclare package Medium = Buildings.Media.Antifreeze.PropyleneGlycolWater(X_a = 0.40, property_T = 293.15) "Propylene glycol water, 40% mass fraction", use_m_flow_in = true, use_T_in = true)  annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {4, -36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Buildings.Fluid.MixingVolumes.MixingVolume vol(nPorts=2,   V = 0.01, redeclare package Medium = Buildings.Media.Antifreeze.PropyleneGlycolWater(X_a = 0.40, property_T = 293.15) "Propylene glycol water, 40% mass fraction", m_flow_nominal = 1, T_start = 293.15, p_start = 1e5)  annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin={34,14},    extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.PrescribedHeatFlow prescribedHeatFlow annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin={-14,36},    extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sensors.TemperatureSensor outletTemperatureHeatExchanger annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {54, 74}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput heatFlow annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-70, 36}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-110, 44}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}})));
protected 
  input Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput inletTemperature2
                                                      annotation(Placement(
        transformation(extent={{-28,-28},{-12,-12}}), iconTransformation(extent
          ={{-28,-28},{-12,-12}})));
public 
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput outletTempHeatExchanger annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {82, 42}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}), iconTransformation(origin = {108, 56}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary bou(redeclare package Medium = Buildings.Media.Antifreeze.PropyleneGlycolWater(X_a = 0.40, property_T = 293.15) "Propylene glycol water, 40% mass fraction", T = 303.15, nPorts = 1) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin={36,-66},    extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput massfluxHeatExchanger
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{66,-6},{86,14}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.FirstOrder firstOrder(T=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-58,-18},{-38,2}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput inletTemperature 
    "Connector of Real input signal"
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-116,-28},{-76,12}})));
initial equation 
  x = 0.0;
  inletTemperature2 = 20.0;

// EQUATION
equation 
// Berechnung der Temperaturspreizung
  currentTempSpread =outletTemperatureHeatExchanger.T - inletTemperature2;
// Proporitonalitätsanteil
  controllerU = desiredTempSpread - currentTempSpread;
// Differentialanteil
  x_diff = der(controllerU);
// Integralanteil
  der(x) = controllerU;
  when heatFlow < 1e-3 or x < x_min or x > x_max then
    reinit(controllerU, 0);
  end when;
// Berechnung des Steuersignals mit dem PID-Regler
  controlSignal = K_p*(controllerU + 1/T_i*x + T_d*x_diff);
// Begrenzung des Volumenstroms
  pressure = maxPressure - controlSignal;
// Berechnung der aktuellen Fließgeschwindigkeit
  flowSpeed = sqrt(2*pressure/(densityRefrigerant*zeta));
// Berechnung des aktuellen Massenstroms
  boundary.m_flow = flowSpeed*crossSectionAreaPipe*densityRefrigerant;

  massfluxHeatExchanger = boundary.m_flow;

  connect(boundary.ports[1], vol.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points={{14,-36},{36,-36},{36,4},{33,4}},          color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(prescribedHeatFlow.port, vol.heatPort) annotation(
    Line(points={{-4,36},{24,36},{24,14}},        color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(outletTemperatureHeatExchanger.port, vol.heatPort) annotation(
    Line(points={{44,74},{24,74},{24,14}},        color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(heatFlow, prescribedHeatFlow.Q_flow) annotation(
    Line(points={{-70,36},{-24,36}},                 color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(inletTemperature2, boundary.T_in)
    annotation (Line(points={{-20,-20},{-20,-32},{-8,-32}}, color={0,0,127}));
connect(outletTempHeatExchanger, outletTemperatureHeatExchanger.T) annotation(
    Line(points={{82,42},{65,42},{65,74}},        color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(vol.ports[2], bou.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points={{35,4},{35,-36},{20,-36},{20,-66},{26,-66}},
                                                 color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(inletTemperature2, firstOrder.y)
    annotation (Line(points={{-20,-20},{-20,-8},{-37,-8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(firstOrder.u, inletTemperature)
    annotation (Line(points={{-60,-8},{-96,-8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end PumpTemperatureControlled;


Doing this, makes Dymola generate a warning: "The following model input signals are assumed to be at their start-value during
simulation, since file "dsu.txt" could not be opened
(No such file or directory):
heatFlow
inletTemperature"
I think this is a pretty fundamental issue (not with this solution, but the original model).

Yes, that is a problem it can be avoided by using inletTemperature(start=...) (at least in Dymola). However, the next problem is that it is then too hot for the cooling fluid, and I don't know how to fix that.
